# How to add more information to the details page of a file in Windows explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, git, file-descriptors

In my previous company, we were working with GIT, which uses hashing technology for identifying purposes. I remember that the commit hash of a file was present in the details of a file (open a file in Windows explorer, right-click, go to the "Details" tab).

However, now I'm working with SourceSafe, and when I look at the mentioned "Details" tab, I see the following entries (freely translated from Dutch):

- Name
- Type
- Path
- Size
- Creation date
- Modification date
- Properties (?)
- Owner
- Computer

So, except for maybe the "Properties (?)" entry, I don't see any place where that information can be written. Is this possible, is it possible using SourceSafe and how?

Comment: Properties/details can vary bsed on file type (extension). Only the properties that come from the file system: Path, Name, Size, Attributes, Creation Time, Last Write TIme, and Last Access Time are common to all files.

Comment: @KeithMiller: thanks for your reply. Do you know how I can add properties for a certain file type?

Comment: I don't know of any on-the-fly method. Properties othr than the file system propeties are metadata defined in the filetype specification.